# How to pass body parameters in REST POST snaplogic?

Tags: rest, post, snaplogic

[Postman sending body parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRdu1.png)

This is my Postman call (rest post) to a Rest Endpoint with Body parameters in `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

How can I do that in Snaplogic with REST `POST` snap? I didn't find how to declare the body parameters (only header and query parameters).

Answer (score 1):

Following are the steps for passing body parameters as `x-www-form-urlencoded` in SnapLogic's REST POST snap.

For this test, I created the following test pipeline.

[image: Pipeline]

I set the parameters to send in a mapper.

[image: Data]

Then I create the content (in another mapper) to pass into the body as follows.

[image: Create Content]

Following is the expanded expression.

[image: Expression]

Then, in the REST POST snap, you need to pass this content in the HTTP entity.

[image: content as http entity]

Also, in the REST POST snap, set the content type.

[image: content type]

Following is the screenshot for successful validation.

[image: success]

So, the idea is to pass the parameters as key-value pairs separated by `&` in the HTTP entity field of REST POST snap. Both the key and the value needs to be URI encoded. Also, the `Content-Type` in the headers section needs to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. And, that should be it.

The required result will be the `$response.entity` object in the output of your REST POST snap.

Hope this helps :)